# How can I fix the error unable to open slave

Tags: archlinux, alsa, bevy

I was using bevy game engine 0.10.1 on Arch Linux avoiding the

```
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:999:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
ALSA lib pcm_dsnoop.c:566:(snd_pcm_dsnoop_open) unable to open slave
cannot connect snake-becy.P.3391259.0:out_000 to system:playback_1
cannot connect snake-becy.P.3391259.2:out_000 to system:playback_1
cannot connect snake-becy.P.3391259.3:out_000 to system:playback_1
ALSA lib pcm_oss.c:397:(_snd_pcm_oss_open) Cannot open device /dev/dsp
ALSA lib pcm_oss.c:397:(_snd_pcm_oss_open) Cannot open device /dev/dsp
```

errors until I realized it was delaying the startup time.
I think it might be because I don't have an audio device on /dev/dsp and alsa-oss is not creating the compatibility layer

I tried installing alsa-oss and restarting alsa service

Comment: had similar issue, setting the default card solved it for me: https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Advanced_Linux_Sound_Architecture#Set_the_default_sound_card